Why is $X e^{\Lambda t}X^{-1}$ the general solution to system of $n$ linear first order ordinary differential equations?
I know that a system of n first order linear ordinary differential equations:
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{dy_1}{dt} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{d^ny_n}{dt^n} \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} a _{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbf{Y}' &= A \mathbf{Y}
\end{align}
$$
is solved by a general solution of the form: $\mathbf{y}(t) = \sum^n_i c_i e^{\lambda_it}\mathbf{x}$,
where $c_i$'s are the initial values, $\lambda_i$ is the i-th eigenvalue, and $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the i-th eigenvector.
I can see why that is the case
However, a textbook that i'm using (Introduction to Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang 5th Edition) proposes that the general solution above can be equivalently expressed as $\mathbf{X}e^{\Lambda t}\mathbf{X}^{-1}$. And i'm having trouble to see why that is the case...
If i expand the proposed expression, i get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1 t}  & & \\ & \ddots  & \\ & & e^{\lambda_n t}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1^{-1} & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_n^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
where did the initial values go? and assuming if these two expressions are equivalent, then where did the inverse eigenvector matrix go in the first expression?

I think the exact expression is $Xe^{\Lambda t}  X^{-1} y(0)$ where $y(0)$ is the initial vector.

okay, but why do we have the inverse eigenvector matrix?

Not $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1^{-1} & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_n^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$ but $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_n\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$
